# How to specify the outer product of certain axis in python?

Tags: python, numpy

may I ask how to calculate the outer product for certain axes of 2 matrices in numpy?
For instance:

```
A = np.arange(24).reshape(3,4,2,1)
B = np.arange(24).reshape(3,4,1,2)
```

And I wish to get a matrix C:

```
C = some_function(A,B)
```

such that

```
C.shape: (3,4,2,2)
```

which means that I just do the outer product for the last 2 axes.

Thanks!

Comment: does C has A or B values in the first two dimensions?

Comment: yes, I think so

Comment: I think np.einsum can do what are you looking for, but I'm not sure which subscripting you should use as a lot of combination will produce shape of (3,4,2,2). 

np.einsum('abcd,hijk->abck',A,B),
np.einsum('abcd,hijk->aick',A,B) ...etc.

if you can give a numerical example with expected output I may be able to find the suitable subscripting

Comment: Thank you! I am actually reading the doc of that function now. And I don't know how to give the example. Give me some time, and I will add numbers to the matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Your arrays are already in the right form so that [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.broadcasting.html) does the outer product for you:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(24).reshape(3,4,2,1)
B = np.arange(24).reshape(3,4,1,2)

C = A * B
C.shape # (3, 4, 2, 2)
```

If you want to perform this product for arrays without the extraenous axes you can add the axes on the fly:

```
A = np.arange(24).reshape(3,4,2)  # note the absence of 1
B = np.arange(24).reshape(3,4,2)

C = A[..., :, None] * B[..., None, :]  # extra axes are added here
C.shape # (3, 4, 2, 2)
```

And just move the `:, None`/`None, :` instruction to the right position if you want to product a different axis:

```
C = A[:, None, ...] * B[None, :, ...]
C.shape # (3, 3, 4, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

does

```
C = np.einsum('...ij,...ik->...ik',A,B)
```

do the trick? C is

```
  [[[[  0,   0],
     [  0,   1]],

    [[  4,   6],
     [  6,   9]],

    [[ 16,  20],
     [ 20,  25]],

    [[ 36,  42],
     [ 42,  49]]],


   [[[ 64,  72],
     [ 72,  81]],

    [[100, 110],
     [110, 121]],

    [[144, 156],
     [156, 169]],

    [[196, 210],
     [210, 225]]],


   [[[256, 272],
     [272, 289]],

    [[324, 342],
     [342, 361]],

    [[400, 420],
     [420, 441]],

    [[484, 506],
     [506, 529]]]])
```

This is a good blog post for understanding einsum: http://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/

PS in your question you already had the extra dimensions added to A and B which would make `*` give an outer product (in 2D version). However einsum can give outer product without the extra dimension:

```
A = np.arange(24).reshape(3,4,2)
B = np.arange(24).reshape(3,4,2)
C = np.einsum('...i,...j->...ij', A, B)
```

Comment: Yes, I think so! You are clever! Thank you very much!